# [ROS2] How to enable logging

Tags: ros, ros2, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having troubles with my ROS2 setup. One common way I use during troubleshooting is logging. Basically, whenever I face an issue, my standard response is: crank up the logging!

My question is: how do I enable logging to file or standard output with ROS2?

- Is there an environment variable that I could not find in the documentation which should be set?
- Is there a flag to an executable?

I tried this:

```
$ ros2 topic list __log_level:=debug
```

But that did not work out..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329045/%5Bros2%5D-how-to-enable-logging/) by [Windel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20680/windel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2019-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment logging to file is not directly possible with ROS2, unless you register a custom logger interface. It will be probably available soon https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-logging/6469/24?u=alsora

For what concerns enabling log to standard output, the command that you used is not entirely correct.
You have to set the logger verbosity for a specific ROS2 application.

The correct one would be something like this (for example for the `publisher_lambda` demo executable)

```
ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher publisher_lambda __log_level:=debug
```

Inside your application, you can log using the following macro (assuming C++ application)

```
RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "This is my log message");
```

By default, the messages will be also logged to a specific topic, named `rosout`. (This behavior can be disabled using the parameter `__log_disable_rosout:=true`)
So you can listen to them using

```
ros2 topic echo /rosout
```

An alternative is to use `rqt` which has plugins for reading and filtering logs

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Windel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20680/windel/) on 2019-07-22**:
Thank you for this explanation. Is the fastrtps internal logger also routed into the rcl logging system? In order to troubleshoot connectivity issues, I would like to see logs from the FastRTPS library.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-07-22**:
No, it isn't.
As a side note, until some time ago logging in Fast-RTPS required a debug build, I'm not aware if they changed this. https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/issues/402

**Comment by [Windel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20680/windel/) on 2019-07-22**:
Btw, I tried a simple `rclpy` script, and `ros2 topic echo /rosout` does not give any output.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-07-22**:
There is probably an error in the implementation of your script.
I suggest you to open a new question about that.
If you want to test this with `rclpy` try the following:

```
ros2 run examples_rclpy_minimal_client client
```

```
ros2 topic echo rosout
```

The client node will log a message saying that it's not finding a server. You should see the message both in the client terminal, as well as in a new terminal using the `echo` command shown above

**Comment by [ssnover95](https://answers.ros.org/users/42866/ssnover95/) on 2020-09-18**:
Have there been any updates with regards to logging to a file in Eloquent or Foxy? Either support for it or perhaps a Github issue tracking the feature? (this is the top result when I search for it, so it'd be great if this page at least could direct one to the right place)